# Understanding C++ template method definition syntax

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a class template:

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
  ... 
  int length() const;
};
```

The definition of `length` would be

```
template <typename T>
int Array<T>::length() const
{
   ...
}
```

But why wouldn't it be? (I)

```
int Array<T>::length() const
{
   ...
}
```

Or maybe: (II)

```
template <typename T>
int Array::length() const
{
   ...
}
```

I guess (II) would be a function template. But actually I cannot understand the logic behind this syntax. Any rules to understand templates syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it can't be `(I)` is easy: Without the `template` line, the compiler would have no choice but to interpret the `<` as a less-than operator, which would definitely not result in a useful function definition.

For `(II)` we need to consider how you would represent a function template of a class template. Say your class looked like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
  ... 
  template <typename U>
  int length() const;
};
```

Now you need to be able to explicitly specify which component takes which template parameter. Without explicitly specifying the `<T>` and `<U>` you would have at minimum a bunch of confusion about which parameter applies to which template. At worst it would be ambiguous and uncompilable.

Answer (score 2):

```
int Array<T>::length() const
{
   ...
}
```

Illegal if:

- you have not declared a class called `T`
- you have not used typedef to give an existing type a new name - `T`

ex:

```
class T;
typedef double T;
using T = double;
```

---

```
template <typename T>
int Array::length() const
{
   ...
}
```

Illegal if:

- you don't have a class called `Array` - different from `template <class T> Array`

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
int Array::length() const
```

There may be partial specializations of a template. How is the compiler supposed to know whether this is a definition for the member of the primary template or a partial specialization?

```
int Array<T>::length() const
```

Every name in C++ must be declared. `T`, if to be used as a template parameter, must also be declared as one. You haven't, therefore the compiler will look for an earlier declaration and issue an error message as he finds none.